# Reshaping Columns in R, based on finding string pattern

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I would like to reshape and create new columns using `dplyr::mutate()` named `propositions`, `condition`, `rank`, `prob`, based on the patterns from `questionType`, and `rank` and `prob` values from `values`.

```
print(dat)
#   questionType  values
# hideRoomA_rank     1     
# hideRoomB_rank     0     
# hideRoomC_rank_inf on    
# hideRoomAorB_rank  0     
# hideRoomAorC_rank  100   
# hideRoomBorC_rank  100
```

I would like to have my final data frame to look like the following

```
print(tidy_dat)
#       questionType values propositions condition rank prob
#     hideRoomA_rank      1        RoomA      hide    1   NA
#     hideRoomB_rank      0        RoomB      hide    0   NA
# hideRoomC_rank_inf     on        RoomC      hide   on   NA
#  hideRoomAorB_rank      0     RoomAorB      hide    0   NA
#  hideRoomAorC_rank    100     RoomAorC      hide  100   NA
#  hideRoomBorC_rank    100     RoomBorC      hide  100   NA
```

---

Reproducible data:

```
dat <- structure(list(questionType = c("hideRoomA_rank", "hideRoomB_rank", 
"hideRoomC_rank_inf", "hideRoomAorB_rank", "hideRoomAorC_rank", 
"hideRoomBorC_rank", "notHideRoomA_rank", "notHideRoomB_rank", 
"notHideRoomC_rank", "seekRoomA_rank", "seekRoomB_rank", "seekRoomC_rank_inf", 
"seekRoomAorB_rank", "seekRoomAorC_rank", "seekRoomBorC_rank", 
"notSeekRoomA_rank", "notSeekRoomB_rank", "notSeekRoomC_rank", 
"hideRoomA_prob", "hideRoomB_prob", "hideRoomC_prob", "hideRoomAorB_prob", 
"hideRoomAorC_prob", "hideRoomBorC_prob", "notHideRoomA_prob", 
"notHideRoomB_prob", "notHideRoomC_prob", "seekRoomA_prob", "seekRoomB_prob", 
"seekRoomC_prob", "seekRoomAorB_prob", "seekRoomAorC_prob", "seekRoomBorC_prob", 
"notSeekRoomA_prob", "notSeekRoomB_prob", "notSeekRoomC_prob"
), values = c("1", "0", "on", "0", "100", "100", "1", "2", "0", 
"2", "0", "on", "0", "100", "50", "1", "5", "0", "0.35", "0.65", 
"0", "1", "0.35", "0.65", "0.65", "0.35", "1", "0.35", "0.65", 
"0", "1", "0.35", "0.65", "0.65", "0.35", "1")), row.names = c(NA, 
-36L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

```
tidy_dat = structure(list(questionType = c("hideRoomA_rank", "hideRoomB_rank", 
"hideRoomC_rank_inf", "hideRoomAorB_rank", "hideRoomAorC_rank", 
"hideRoomBorC_rank", "notHideRoomA_rank", "notHideRoomB_rank", 
"notHideRoomC_rank", "seekRoomA_rank", "seekRoomB_rank", "seekRoomC_rank_inf", 
"seekRoomAorB_rank", "seekRoomAorC_rank", "seekRoomBorC_rank", 
"notSeekRoomA_rank", "notSeekRoomB_rank", "notSeekRoomC_rank", 
"hideRoomA_prob", "hideRoomB_prob", "hideRoomC_prob", "hideRoomAorB_prob", 
"hideRoomAorC_prob", "hideRoomBorC_prob", "notHideRoomA_prob", 
"notHideRoomB_prob", "notHideRoomC_prob", "seekRoomA_prob", "seekRoomB_prob", 
"seekRoomC_prob", "seekRoomAorB_prob", "seekRoomAorC_prob", "seekRoomBorC_prob", 
"notSeekRoomA_prob", "notSeekRoomB_prob", "notSeekRoomC_prob"
), values = c("1", "0", "on", "0", "100", "100", "1", "2", "0", 
"2", "0", "on", "0", "100", "50", "1", "5", "0", "0.35", "0.65", 
"0", "1", "0.35", "0.65", "0.65", "0.35", "1", "0.35", "0.65", 
"0", "1", "0.35", "0.65", "0.65", "0.35", "1"), propositions = c("RoomA", 
"RoomB", "RoomC", "RoomAorB", "RoomAorC", "RoomBorC", "notRoomA", 
"notRoomB", "notRoomC", "RoomA", "RoomB", "RoomC", "RoomAorB", 
"RoomAorC", "RoomBorC", "notRoomA", "notRoomB", "notRoomC", "RoomA", 
"RoomB", "RoomC", "RoomAorB", "RoomAorC", "RoomBorC", "notRoomA", 
"notRoomB", "notRoomC", "RoomA", "RoomB", "RoomC", "RoomAorB", 
"RoomAorC", "RoomBorC", "notRoomA", "notRoomB", "notRoomC"), 
    condition = c("hide", "hide", "hide", "hide", "hide", "hide", 
    "hide", "hide", "hide", "seek", "seek", "seek", "seek", "seek", 
    "seek", "seek", "seek", "seek", "hide", "hide", "hide", "hide", 
    "hide", "hide", "hide", "hide", "hide", "seek", "seek", "seek", 
    "seek", "seek", "seek", "seek", "seek", "seek"), rank = c("1", 
    "0", "on", "0", "100", "100", "1", "2", "0", "2", "0", "on", 
    "0", "100", "50", "1", "5", "0", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), prob = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, 0.35, 0.65, 0, 1, 0.35, 0.65, 0.65, 0.35, 1, 0.35, 
    0.65, 0, 1, 0.35, 0.65, 0.65, 0.35, 1)), row.names = c(NA, 
-36L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 4):

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

dat |>
  mutate(
    qtype = str_replace(questionType, "Room", "_Room")
  ) |>
  separate(
    qtype, 
    into = c("condition", "propositions", "name"),
    sep = "_", extra = "drop"
  ) |>
  mutate(
    rank = ifelse(name == "rank", values, NA),
    prob = ifelse(name == "prob", values, NA)
  )
# # A tibble: 36 × 7
#    questionType       values condition propositions name  rank  prob 
#    <chr>              <chr>  <chr>     <chr>        <chr> <chr> <chr>
#  1 hideRoomA_rank     1      hide      RoomA        rank  1     NA   
#  2 hideRoomB_rank     0      hide      RoomB        rank  0     NA   
#  3 hideRoomC_rank_inf on     hide      RoomC        rank  on    NA   
#  4 hideRoomAorB_rank  0      hide      RoomAorB     rank  0     NA   
#  5 hideRoomAorC_rank  100    hide      RoomAorC     rank  100   NA   
#  6 hideRoomBorC_rank  100    hide      RoomBorC     rank  100   NA   
#  7 notHideRoomA_rank  1      notHide   RoomA        rank  1     NA   
#  8 notHideRoomB_rank  2      notHide   RoomB        rank  2     NA   
#  9 notHideRoomC_rank  0      notHide   RoomC        rank  0     NA   
# 10 seekRoomA_rank     2      seek      RoomA        rank  2     NA   
# # … with 26 more rows
# # ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do as follows:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

dat %>%
  mutate(propositions = str_extract(questionType, "Room[:alpha:]+"),
         conditions = str_extract(questionType, "[:alpha:]+(?=Room)"),
         rank = if_else(str_detect(questionType, "rank"), 
                        values,
                        NA_character_),
         prob = if_else(str_detect(questionType, "prob"), 
                        values, 
                        NA_character_))

# A tibble: 36 × 6
#   questionType       values propositions conditions rank  prob 
#   <chr>              <chr>  <chr>        <chr>      <chr> <chr>
# 1 hideRoomA_rank     1      RoomA        hide       1     NA   
# 2 hideRoomB_rank     0      RoomB        hide       0     NA   
# 3 hideRoomC_rank_inf on     RoomC        hide       on    NA   
# 4 hideRoomAorB_rank  0      RoomAorB     hide       0     NA   
# 5 hideRoomAorC_rank  100    RoomAorC     hide       100   NA   
# 6 hideRoomBorC_rank  100    RoomBorC     hide       100   NA   
# 7 notHideRoomA_rank  1      RoomA        notHide    1     NA   
# 8 notHideRoomB_rank  2      RoomB        notHide    2     NA   
# 9 notHideRoomC_rank  0      RoomC        notHide    0     NA   
# 10 seekRoomA_rank    2      RoomA        seek       2     NA   
# … with 26 more rows
```